# WordPress Get Featured Img Alt Blank using Orbit Slider

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Long story story I'm using WordPress and a orbit slider that comes with Zurb Foundation. I quickly found a WordPress plugin that makes use of the Orbit Slider which works great apart from the fact it doesn't use `alt=""` which is something I'm keen to fix. I'm not the best person at WordPress codex and php but none the less I've given it a go.

I have added the following get_post_meta data:

`$imgalt = get_post_meta( $imgid->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );`

Which it should feltch the alt tag information from
`$imgid = get_post_thumbnail_id();`

I call this data later using:

```
echo `'<img class="orbit-slide" src="' . $urlimg . '" alt="' . $imgalt .'" />';`
```

But sadly I'm greeted with a empty field like so `alt=""`

I'll add the full code so you understand more about what I'm trying to adapt:

```
<?php foreach($slider_posts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
       $options = $this->get_options();
       // Get the title
       $title = get_the_title();
       // Get the excerpt
       $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
       // Fetch image for slider
       $imgsize = $options->imgSize;
       $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), ''.$imgsize.'' ); $urlimg = $img['0'];
       // Fetch image ID (then applied to content divs for styling individual content areas)
       $imgid = get_post_thumbnail_id();
       // Get image alt
       $imgalt = get_post_meta( $imgid->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
       // Fetch thumbnail for slider
       $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'orbit-slide-small' ); $urlthumb = $thumb['0'];
       // Slide Caption
       $caption = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sliderCaption', TRUE);
       // Target exists?
       $target = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sliderTarget', TRUE);
       // If so, target URL
       $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sliderUrl', TRUE);
       // If alt used lets init alt tag
       if( $caption == TRUE ) {
              $datacaption = 'data-caption="#slide-' . get_the_ID() . '"';
       } else {
              $datacaption = '';
       }
       // Output the thumbnail
       $datathumb = 'data-thumb="' . $urlthumb . '"';
       // If slide has target
       if( $link == TRUE ) {
              echo '<a target="' . $target . '" href="' . $link . '"' . $datacaption . $datathumb . '><img class="orbit-slide" alt="' . $imgalt .'" src="' . $urlimg . '" /></a>';
              // If not and has html content
                     } elseif( !empty($post->post_content) ) {
              echo '<div class="content" style=""' . $datathumb . '>';
              echo '<div class="slide-content slide-content-' . $imgid . '">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
              echo '<img class="orbit-slide" src="' . $urlimg . '" alt="' . $imgalt .'" />';
              echo '</div>';
              // Otherwise, lets just use images
                     } else {
              echo '<img class="orbit-slide" src="' . $urlimg . '"' . $datacaption . $datathumb . ' alt="' . $imgalt .'"/>';
       }
endforeach;  ?>
```

Comment: That looks correct. Have you tried replacing the definition for `$imgalt` with something static (i.e. `"foobar"` or `"test"`) and seeing if that works? It may be a problem with `get_post_meta`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code :

```
$imgid = get_post_thumbnail_id();
// Get image alt
$imgalt = get_post_meta( $imgid->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
```

[get_post_thumbnail_id()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) returns an ID, so `$imgid` should contain it. So you should just use `$imgid` instead of `$imgid->ID` inside `get_post_meta()`. Try this :

```
$imgalt = get_post_meta( $imgid, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
```